# procedure for birkat kohanim

Tags: sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, birchas-kohanim

The Mechaber in Orach Chaim 128:13 writes:

> "מתחילין הכהנים לומר יברכך: הגה וי"א שגם מלת יברכך יקרא אותם ש"צ תחלה [טור ור"ן פ' הקורא והגהות מיימוני] (וכן נוהגים בכל מדינות אלו) ואח"כ מקרא אותם ש"ץ מלה במלה והם עונים אחריו על כל מלה עד שיסיימו פסוק ראשון ואז עונים הצבור אמן וכן אחר פסוק ב' וכן אחר פסוק ג':
>
> The kohanim begin to say "Yevarechecha." (Ram"a: Some say that even the word "Yevarechecha" is called out by the cantor first, and so is our custom in these countries.) Afterward, the cantor calls out to them word by word, and they respond after him with each word, until they conclude the first verse. And then the congregation answers, "Amen." And so after the second verse; and so after the third verse."

Yet many communities of the Sefaradim and the Edot Hamizrach have the chazan call even the word yevarechecha.
Why and when did this practice change?

Comment: Change? Why do you think all Sefardim ever followed the Mechabber's position?

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, the Minhag in many communities such as Eretz Yisrael and Bavel was once like the Rambam and Shulchan Aruch, but the Ashkenazi Minhag has some procedural benefits, as it's easier for everyone to answer Amen to the Beracha. Hence, the Ben Ish Chai and Rav Ovadia convinced many communities to change for the better. Those who maintain the Minhag are not in bad standing, though. (Yechave Da'at 4:10 in the footnote, Halichot Olam vol. 1 Teztaveh 1, Yalkut Yosef 128:42, and [Halacha Berurah 128:51](http://www.otzar.org/wotzar/book.aspx?143806&pageid=P0400), who quotes the Acharonim who testify the Minhag was previously like the Rambam and Maran) Nevertheless, the Teimani Minhag is still like the Rambam (Shulchan Aruch HaMekutzar 20:11)

I personally know a gentleman who came from Iran in 2000 and regularly says Yevarechecha without it being called to him in our Minyan.

**ילקוט יוסף קכח:מב**

> מב. יש אומרים שאין השליח צבור מקריא לכהנים תיבת "יברכך", אלא הכהנים מתחילים בעצמם "יברכך". ויש אומרים שגם תיבת "יברכך" צריך שהשליח צבור יקריא אותה לכהנים. ואף על פי שהנוהגים כסברא ראשונה יש להם על מה שיסמוכו, מכל מקום טוב ונכון שגם תיבת "יברכך" יקריא אותה לכהנים. והדבר יעשה בהסכמת כל הקהל. וישאו ברכה מאת ה'. [ובפרט שפעמים רבות כשאין מקריאים תיבת יברכך, הרי אין הצבור יכול לענות אמן אחר ברכת הכהנים, בהיותם מסמיכים תיבת יברכך לברכה, והצבור לא שומע את סיום הברכה].מב)